# Counting elements of a given length in a group via GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

I have a finitely presented group G in GAP, for example with the following generators and relations:
generators = $[ f1, f2, f3, f4 ]$
relators = $[
 f1^2,
 f2^2,
 f3^2,
 f4^2,
 (f3*f2)^2,
 (f2*f1)^3,
 (f1*f4)^3,
 (f3*f1)^3,
 (f4*f3)^3,
 (f2*f4)^3 ]$

> Question: How can I count the number of elements G that have length equal to $i$ (which means that the element is a non-zero product in G of exactly $i$ generators $f_i$ in a minimal way)?

Comment: That looks like the standard Coxeter presentation of $S_5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt GAP doesnt give me the order for a while, so I thought it must be an infnite group. But it is just an example anyway of how the input of a group looks for this problem in GAP.

Comment: GAP returns the `Size` of the group after a few ms on my computer.

Comment: @ahulpke I used the wrong example. I poseted the correct one now. It seems to be infinite.

Comment: You really should not change a question that has been correctly answered! It is better to ask a new question. It would also be helpful if you wrote presentations in GAP format so that they could be easily copied and pasted.

Comment: @DerekHolt I did not change the question. This group is just an example and I accidently pasted the wrong one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done for finitely presented groups in general, because there are groups with undecidable word problems. But for possibly infinite finitely presented groups that are shortlex automatic or have complete rewriting systems, you can use the KBMAG package to do this.

Here is an easy example with an infinite Coxeter group.

```
gap> LoadPackage("kbmag");
true
gap> F := FreeGroup(3);;
gap> G := F/[F.1^2, F.2^2, F.3^2, (F.1*F.2)^2, (F.1*F.3)^3, (F.2*F.3)^7];;
gap> R := KBMAGRewritingSystem(G);;
gap> A := AutomaticStructure(R);;
```

You can use the function $\mathsf{EnumerateReducedWords}$ to list shortlex least representatives of group elements of specified length. So, for example,

```
gap> Length(EnumerateReducedWords(R,0,3));
16
gap> Length(EnumerateReducedWords(R,4,4));
9
```

tells us that there are 16 elements of lengths 0 to 3, and 9 elements of length exactly 4.

You can also compute the exact growth function of the group as a rational function.

```
gap> GrowthFunction(R);
(x_1^10+4*x_1^9+8*x_1^8+11*x_1^7+12*x_1^6+12*x_1^5+12*x_1^4+11*x_1^3+8*x_1^2+4\
*x_1+1)/(x_1^10+x_1^9-x_1^7-x_1^6-x_1^5-x_1^4-x_1^3+x_1+1)
```

The coefficients $a_n$ of the Taylor series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ of this would give the number of elements of length $n$, but I don't know whether GAP has a function to compute series expansions.

Comment: Thank you. That solves the problem in a perfect way. It would indeed be nice to have a taylor expansion function for GAP, but one can use wolfram alpha when GAP gives the series.

Comment: That is very impressive functionality (that I wasn't aware of). I will add Taylor series functionality to the next release, in the meantime, there is code for this at https://www.dropbox.com/s/m50tkk4h1d7aw8n/tayser.g?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

If your group is sufficiently small (as your example is), and you can convert into a permutation group, you can use `GrowthFunctionOfGroup`:

```
gap> p:=Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(G));
Group([ (2,3)(4,5)(6,8), (1,2)(5,7)(8,9), (2,4)(3,5)(9,10), (4,6)(5,8)(7,9) ])
gap> GrowthFunctionOfGroup(p);
[ 1, 4, 9, 15, 20, 22, 20, 15, 9, 4, 1 ]
```

So there are 4 elements of length 1, 9 of length 2, and so on.

If the group is much larger (so storing elemnts is hard) or even infinite, this is a much harder problem.

Comment: Thanks, for infinite examples this takes very long. Is there a way to just get the number of elements of a fixed (small) length, like length 2,3,4?